# Title bar indication for new activity in Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

This feature is present on Meta and does work but does not work with Stack Overflow. There are activities and still the title bar does not display the same.

Is it going to be implemented in Stack Overflow too?

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - The OP means that on SO, you don't get notification that new questions have been posted (it doesn't show on the browser title for the page).

Comment: Ahh... I misunderstood "Title Bar" @oded

Answer (score 2):

No.

There is so much traffic on the front page of Stack Overflow that the indicator will pretty much be always on. It is not very useful on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Or maybe the question can be edited for a particular question or answer that you asked and is presently the current page but minimized?

Comment: @NarendraPathai - I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear but I mean, suppose I asked a question and that page is currently open in the browser. Now suppose I minimize the window to do something else and there is an answer to the question then it should show the notification in title bar. I hope I am clear this time.

Comment: @NarendraPathai - When you open the page back up it will notify you about that. Now, is this different from the question you asked?